# How to find variable name from a list of class in a package

Tags: java

My Eclipse has a bug if the fieldname is `mFieldname` the `getter` and `setter` should be `getMFieldName` and `setMFieldname` respectively instead it is `getmFieldName` and `setmFieldName`.I need to identify all such cases.I was trying to read from each *.java file to identify such case. But this was very difficult since my project contains lot of files and sub packages

If anybody knows the solution please help

Comment: Post your code, it's easier to guide you.

Comment: You should know that not many use prefixes for instance variables in Java. (This does not attempt to answer the question)

Comment: You could use a regexp search, something like `set[a-z]*` should do it, but you will have to manual check results. Another option is to use something like checkstyle or PMD to find the candidates

Comment: Did you consider a simple full-text search in your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should use reflection and use regular expression to match your case

```
public static void match(String name,String line)
{   

      String pattern = "("+name+".)([a-z][A-Z]\\w+)";
      // line = "private java.lang.String com.poc.Example.mName";
      // Create a Pattern object
      Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);

      // Now create matcher object.
      Matcher m = r.matcher(line);
      if (m.find( )) {
       /*  System.out.println("Found value: " + m.group(0) );
         System.out.println("Found value: " + m.group(1) );
        System.out.println("Found value: " + m.group(2) );*/
        list.add(m.group(1)+m.group(2));
      } 
}       public static void getFields(String className)
{
    //Field fields[]=a.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
    Field fields[];
    try {
        fields = Class.forName(className).getDeclaredFields();
        for(Field f:fields)
        {
            //System.out.println(f.toString());
            match(className,f.toString());
        }
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }catch (ExceptionInInitializerError e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (MissingResourceException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}
```

//This is my code

```
public class Main {
private static List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
private static List<String> name = new ArrayList<String>();

public static String getSubPackage(String packageName) {
    try {
        getClassNamesFromPackage(packageName);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    packageName = packageName.replace("/", ".");
    packageName = packageName.substring(0, packageName.lastIndexOf('.'));
    return packageName;
}

public static List<String> getClassNamesFromPackage(String packageName)
        throws IOException, URISyntaxException {
    ClassLoader classLoader = Thread.currentThread()
            .getContextClassLoader();
    URL packageURL;

    packageName = packageName.replace(".", "/");

    packageURL = classLoader.getResource(packageName);
    if (packageURL == null)
        System.out.println(packageName);
    if (new URI(packageURL.toString()) == null)
        System.out.println(packageURL);
    URI uri = new URI(packageURL.toString());

    File folder = new File(uri.getPath());
    // won't work with path which contains blank (%20)
    // File folder = new File(packageURL.getFile());
    File[] content = folder.listFiles();
    // System.out.println(folder);
    String entryName;
    for (File actual : content) {
        entryName = actual.getName();
        if (entryName.contains(".class")) {
            // System.out.println(entryName);
            // System.out.println(entryName.substring(0,
            // entryName.lastIndexOf('.')));
            entryName = entryName.substring(0, entryName.lastIndexOf('.'));

            // System.out.println(actual.getName());

            name.add(packageName.replace("/", ".") + "." + entryName);
        } else {
            if (!(entryName.contains(".xml"))
                    && !(entryName.contains(".properties"))
                    && !(entryName.contains(".wsdl"))
                    && !(entryName.contains(".mine"))
                    && !(entryName.contains(".r15857"))
                    && !(entryName.contains(".r15939"))) {
                packageName = packageName.replace("/", ".");
                packageName = packageName + "." + entryName;
                packageName = getSubPackage(packageName);
            }
        }

    }

    return name;
}

public static void match(String name, String line) {

    String pattern = "(" + name + ".)([a-z][A-Z]\\w+)";
    // line = "private java.lang.String com.poc.Example.mName";
    // Create a Pattern object
    Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);

    // Now create matcher object.
    Matcher m = r.matcher(line);
    if (m.find()) {
        /*
         * System.out.println("Found value: " + m.group(0) );
         * System.out.println("Found value: " + m.group(1) );
         * System.out.println("Found value: " + m.group(2) );
         */
        list.add(m.group(1) + m.group(2));
    }

}

public static void getFields(String className) {
    // Field fields[]=a.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
    Field fields[];
    try {
        fields = Class.forName(className).getDeclaredFields();
        for (Field f : fields) {
            // System.out.println(f.toString());
            match(className, f.toString());
        }
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ExceptionInInitializerError e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (MissingResourceException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    // System.out.println(a.getClass().getName());

}

@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    // Example a = new Example();
    // Example1 b = new Example1();

    // Class exmple = a.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
    String packageName = "com.oneassist";
    getClassNamesFromPackage(packageName);
    System.out.println(name.size());
    Iterator<String> iterator = name.iterator();
    System.out.println(name);
    String className = "";
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        className = iterator.next();
        // Class act = Class.forName(packageName+"."+className);
        // getFields(act);

        // System.out.println(className);
        /*
         * Class cls = Class.forName(className);
         * 
         * @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") Constructor ctor =
         * cls.getConstructor(); Object object = ctor.newInstance();
         */

        // System.out.println(className);
        getFields(className);

    }
    System.out.println(list);
    System.out.println("size =" + list.size());
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Well, there isn't an easier way to modify the changes now. Have you considered using project management tools such as git? You can undo what you just did using git or SVN.

For now, do a Ctrl+H java search and search for "setmFieldName". Now you would see a couple of options. Select 'method' , 'limit to all occurrences' option and un-check the 'Application libraries' and 'JRE' in Search-in options of the java search. The search would return back all the occurrences.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working in Eclipse, you can go to Search->File and put "getmFieldName" in the "Containing text:" box and "*.java" in the "File name patterns" box.  That will search your workspace for Java files with the text getMFieldName.

Also, I don't remember if Eclipse does this or not, but with NetBeans and Intellij you can right click on a class or method and select a Find Usages option.

As an aside, it is not a bug with Eclipse but rather an issue of how the methods were named originally.  In addition, "getMFieldName" is not a standard naming convention.  Usually it would be getFieldName.  For example, if your variable was price, Java convention is

```
getPrice()
```

and

```
setPrice(double newPrice)
```

getMPrice() will of course compile and run.  It is just now what most programmers are expecting.